# Encountering a "429 Error" in Pytrends version 4.9.2

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to extract data from Google Trends using Pytrends (Version 4.9.2) in Python.

The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

**Error Message:** 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sorry/index?continue=https://trends.google.com/trends/api/autocomplete/sam%25E%3Fhl%3Den-AR&hl=en-AR&q=EgQ2SrpGGN3NtakGIi9Dn3cTx21dvhe21wy8DGg6fcfZUwhfdPX0_4zqJrTLmq-P5xdsEzvQW88htENHMzIBcloBQw (Caused by ResponseError('too many 429 error responses'))

**Note:** I'm encountering this error during the very first execution itself.

I've already incorporated retries and back-off mechanisms into the Pytrends request configuration to address this issue. However, the problem persists.